# Spring Boot Rest API and Angular crossorigin how to set in Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: angular, spring

I am doing spring Boot rest API To angular connection with localhost works but how to use in Amazon EC2 , which replace in @CrossOrigin

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class UserController {
        
    @Autowired
    private UserService service;
}
```